# Django - Handle KeyError event (API)

Tags: python, django, django-models, openweathermap

I make a little weather app with Python/Django. I took actual weather data from openweathermap.org. I set up my project, create search field to search a city and connect with API and everything works fine.. until you type a wrong letter (e.g. chikago). Then I get a KeyError.
[image]

Here you can see my code
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
    API_KEY = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=123456789'
    city = request.POST.get('search_input')

    res = requests.get(API_KEY.format(city)).json()
    if city == '':
        city = 'Berlin'

    city_weather = {
        'city': res['name'],
        'temperature': res['main']['temp'],
        'description': res['weather'][0]['description'],
        'icon': res['weather'][0]['icon']
    }
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', {'data': city_weather})
```

If I look up the inspector I see a error 404 so I tried to add a `handle404` in the base urls.py but it doesnt catch the internal error. Also the openweathermap response with a error 404 message: `res {'cod': '404', 'message': 'city not found'}`.

Is there a way I can handle the error message into a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the response code of the request you have made using [**`.status_code`**](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) attribute

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests


def index(request):
    API_KEY = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=123456789'
    city = request.POST.get('search_input')

    request_response = requests.get(API_KEY.format(city))
    if request_response.status_code == 200:
        res = request_response.json()
        city_weather = {
            'city': res['name'],
            'temperature': res['main']['temp'],
            'description': res['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon': res['weather'][0]['icon']
        }
        return render(request, 'weather/index.html', {'data': city_weather})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to convert request to json object. I cannot write code in detail as it was shared above.
Good luck